# ShakeSpeare connection in the King James Bible

Tags: bible-versions

In the book of Psalms chapter 46 Countdown 46 words from the beginning of this psalm and you will find the word "**Shake**." Count up 46 words from the end of this psalm and you will find the word "**Spear**." Thus, 46 words down added to 46 words up in the 46th psalm will give the name "Shakespeare".

**Question- What year did the first edition of the King James Bible published?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is *publicated* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The King James Bible or "Authorised Version" was first published in
1611. Translation began in 1604.

Your observation about Psalm 46 appears in the book "The Shakespeare Code" by Virginia M Andrews , published in 2006.

The author states that Shakespeare was part of the translation committee for KJB , and left clues of this;

However she also states Shakespeare didn't write 'The Plays' , her main 'suspect' being the Earl of Oxford, who was educated to the appropriate standard, and was in the right places at the right times.

Comment: We are only man and not perfect and yes we must admit there is a lot of the Bible that has been edited and left out. There is enough truth left though.